# How to get whole part of a sentence to move down on resize

Tags: html, resize, sass

I have a sentence in h1 tag. On resize I want the last three words to jump down together not just one at a time, since the last three words are a tagline and it wouldn't make sense if they get separated. [Here](http://update.mrskitson.ca) is the live site.

Here is the HTML:

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
    <div id="inner-header" class="wrap clearfix">
       <div id="title">
       <!-- to use a image just replace the bloginfo('name') with your img src and remove the surrounding <p> -->
        <h1 id="logo" class="h1">
                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                    <?php bloginfo('name'); ?><span class="subtitle">
                    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></span>
                </a>
            </h1>
       </div>
    <nav role="navigation">
       <?php bones_main_nav(); ?>
    </nav>
</div> <!-- end #inner-header -->
```

and the scss:

```
.header {
    #title {
        @include span-columns(23 ,24); 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .subtitle {
        font-size: 0.3em; 
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    .nav { 
        @include span-columns(24 omega ,24); 
        margin-top: 289px;
    }
    #logo {
        a { 
           color: #fff; 
           font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive; /*font-size: 2.5em;*/ 
           text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #B6CEBF,
                        0.707px 0.707px 0 #B6CEBF,
                        1.414px 1.414px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        2.121px 2.121px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        2.828px 2.828px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        3.536px 3.536px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        4.243px 4.243px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        4.95px 4.95px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        5.657px 5.657px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        6.364px 6.364px 0 #B6CEBF, 
                        7.071px 7.071px 0 #B6CEBF;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are thinking on make your site responsive, then you have a better solution, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.subtitle {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.3em; 
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

Setting the `display` to `inline-block` will keep the element's contents together (a behavior of `block` elements), but still keep it inline with other text.

You should also look at making some other adjustments so the title can be 100% width, and the navigation still gets positioned properly:

```
#logo {
    margin: 80px 0 0;
}
.header #title {
    height: 289px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.header .nav {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.header .nav ul {
    /* Add the .clearfix class to this ul */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about responsive `@media` queries here. There are few ways to do this, but this is the fastest:

Add this rule to you scss:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .subtitle{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

#### Aside

Bones comes with other scss files, edit `_base.scss` for general styles, but for custom styles on resize edit files like `_768up.scss`, also read the info inside the `style.scss` file to get more info about the media queries. Bones comes with an awesome documentation.

#### Further reading

- [Nice tutorial about media queries from CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
- [Media Queries Spec from W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)
- [CSS media queries at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)